# How to Render a Map as a property in a Grails 4 JSON View

Tags: json, grails, micronaut

I'm trying to render a JSON view that has a property that is a `Map`.  I would like it to render in JSON as a sub-object. This seems like it should be very easy, but I can't find it documented anywhere.  I've created an [example project on GitHub](https://github.com/tonyerskine/rendermapexample).

#### Domain Class

```
class Breakfast {
    String meat
    String eggs
    String side
}
```

#### Controller

```
class FooController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    
    def index() {
        Map<String, Breakfast> mealsByPerson = [
            Tom: new Breakfast(meat: "bacon", eggs: "scrambled", side: "hashbrowns"),
            Jack: new Breakfast(meat: "sausage", eggs: "over easy", side: "pancakes")
        ]

        render template: "foo", model: [cost: 12.34f, date: new Date(), mealsByPerson: mealsByPerson]
    }
}
```

##### `/foo/_foo.gson`

```
import rendermapexample.Breakfast

model {
    Float cost
    Date date
    Map<String, Breakfast> mealsByPerson
}

json {
    date date
    cost cost
    mealsByPerson mealsByPerson // HOW DO I RENDER THIS
}
```

#### This is the JSON I want to render

```
{
    "cost": 12.34,
    "date": "2021-09-25T01:11:39Z",
    "mealsByPerson": {
        "Tom": {
            "eggs": "scrambled",
            "meat": "bacon",
            "side": "hashbrowns"
        },
        "Jack": {
            "eggs": "over easy",
            "meat": "sausage",
            "side": "pancakes"
        }
    }
}
```

#### This is the Error I get

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Error rendering view: null
    at grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer$Trait$Helper.renderViewForTemplate(ResponseRenderer.groovy:617)
    at grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer$Trait$Helper.render(ResponseRenderer.groovy:353)
    at rendermapexample.FooController.index(FooController.groovy:12)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: grails.views.ViewRenderException: Error rendering view: null
    at grails.views.AbstractWritableScript.writeTo(AbstractWritableScript.groovy:43)
    at grails.views.mvc.GenericGroovyTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(GenericGroovyTemplateView.groovy:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:317)
    at grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer$Trait$Helper.renderViewForTemplate(ResponseRenderer.groovy:614)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at grails.plugin.json.converters.InstantJsonConverter.handles(InstantJsonConverter.groovy:18)
    at grails.plugin.json.builder.DefaultJsonGenerator.findConverter(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:457)
    at grails.plugin.json.builder.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.json.builder.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMapEntry(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:419)
...
```

#### I can't do this:

The render statement below creates the JSON I want in this simple example,
but my real-world problem needs more control over rendering than `as JSON` provides

```
render ([cost: 12.34f, date: new Date(), mealsByPerson: mealsByPerson] as JSON)
```

### Example Project

https://github.com/tonyerskine/rendermapexample

### Update:

I posted a related question here in response to a comment below: [How do I render a map of domain objects using a Grails 4 JSON View](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69352644/715608)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `_foo.gson` to the following:

```
import rendermapexample.Breakfast

model {
    Float cost
    Date date
    Map<String, Breakfast> mealsByPerson
}

json {
    date date
    cost cost
    mealsByPerson g.render(mealsByPerson) {}
}
```

The response will include the following:

```
{
"cost": 12.34,
"date": "2021-09-27T17:24:14Z",
"mealsByPerson": {
    "Jack": {
        "eggs": "over easy",
        "meat": "sausage",
        "side": "pancakes"
    },
    "Tom": {
        "eggs": "scrambled",
        "meat": "bacon",
        "side": "hashbrowns"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass other attributes to the `_breakfast.gson` template?  For example, `mealsByPerson g.render(mealsByPerson, model: [allCaps: true]) {}`

Comment: Yes.  If you can describe the desired output I can show you how to generate that.

Comment: Thanks.  I added `Update 1` in the question describing the desired output.

Comment: "Thanks. I added Update 1 in the question describing the desired output. " -Starting out by numbering the updates suggests there may be more.  Rather than letting this question be a string of questions you should consider posting a new question to address the new concern..

Comment: Good point. Sorry about that.  I've posted the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69352644/715608

Answer (score -2):

You need a method in your 'BreakFast' class to export to JSON/XML/LinkedHashMap (or something) which can be returned as a string in the response to the client (ie getJson, getXml, etc )

Either that or you need to do the conversion there in your controller; I would suggest the method in your class as it is cleaner and allows for re-use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Community seems to understand though. Only moderators seem to have an issue. I'll gladly remove answer though if moderator thinks this is 'unhelpful' and continues to state answers are unhelpful.