# How do I render a map of domain objects using a Grails 4 JSON View

Tags: json, grails, gson

This is a follow on questions to: [How to Render a Map as a property in a Grails 4 JSON View](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69322504/715608)

I have the following JSON view and I would like to render the values of `mealsByPerson` map using the `_breakfast.gson` template.  In addition, I would like to be able to pass the `allCaps` model attribute from `_foo.gson` to `breakfast.gson`

##### `/foo/_foo.gson`

```
import rendermapexample.Breakfast

model {
    Float cost
    Date date
    Map<String, Breakfast> mealsByPerson
    Boolean allCaps
}

json {
    date date
    cost cost
    mealsByPerson g.render(mealsByPerson){}  //HOW DO I PASS `allCaps` to this template?

    // This doesn't work  
    // mealsByPerson g.render(mealsByPerson, model: [allCaps: true]){} 
}
```

##### `/breaskfast/_breaskfast.gson`

```
import rendermapexample.Breakfast

model {
    Breakfast breakfast
    Boolean allCaps
}

json {
    meat allCaps ? breakfast.meat.toUpperCase() : breakfast.meat
    eggs allCaps ? breakfast.eggs.toUpperCase() : breakfast.eggs
    side allCaps ? breakfast.side.toUpperCase() : breakfast.side
}
```

#### FooController

```
package rendermapexample

class FooController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    
    def index() {
        Map<String, Breakfast> mealsByPerson = [
            Tom: new Breakfast(meat: "bacon", eggs: "scrambled", side: "hashbrowns"),
            Jack: new Breakfast(meat: "sausage", eggs: "over easy", side: "pancakes")
        ]

        render template: "foo", model: [
            cost: 12.34f, 
            date: new Date(), 
            mealsByPerson: mealsByPerson, 
            allCaps: params.boolean("allCaps")
        ]
    }
}
```

#### Desired output

##### `http://localhost:8080/foo`

```
{
    "cost": 12.34,
    "date": "2021-09-25T01:11:39Z",
    "mealsByPerson": {
        "Tom": {
            "eggs": "scrambled",
            "meat": "bacon",
            "side": "hashbrowns"
        },
        "Jack": {
            "eggs": "over easy",
            "meat": "sausage",
            "side": "pancakes"
        }
    }
}
```

##### `http://localhost:8080/foo?allCaps=true`

```
{
    "cost": 12.34,
    "date": "2021-09-25T01:11:39Z",
    "mealsByPerson": {
        "Tom": {
            "eggs": "SCRAMBLED",
            "meat": "BACON",
            "side": "HASHBROWNS"
        },
        "Jack": {
            "eggs": "OVER EASY",
            "meat": "SAUSAGE",
            "side": "PANCAKES"
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example Project

https://github.com/tonyerskine/rendermapexample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this finally worked

#### `_foo.gson`

```
import rendermapexample.Breakfast

model {
    Float cost
    Date date
    Map<String, Breakfast> mealsByPerson
    Boolean allCaps
}

json {
    date date
    cost cost
    mealsByPerson tmpl."/foo/mealsByPerson2"([mealsByPerson: mealsByPerson, allCaps: allCaps])
}
```

#### `_mealsByPerson2.gson`

```
model {
    Map mealsByPerson
    Boolean allCaps
}

json {
    for(Map.Entry entry : mealsByPerson) {
        "${entry.key}" tmpl."/breakfast/breakfast"(breakfast:entry.value, allCaps:allCaps)
    }
}
```

### Note: This does *NOT* work for `_mealByPerson.gson`

You must use a standard loop rather than an `each` closure for this to work

```
model {
    Map mealsByPerson
    Boolean allCaps
}

json {
    mealsByPerson.each { Map.Entry entry ->
        "${entry.key}" tmpl."/breakfast/breakfast"(breakfast:entry.value, allCaps:allCaps)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Please review my **[improved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69421019/6419922)**.

This is my (kind of) old-school approach:

**First**, since the allCaps requirement might be useful not only for that particular controller/action, I would add an `asMap` method to the `Breakfast` domain class itself. It capitalizes all String properties if its param `allCaps` is true, and returns a `Map` with all object's properties:

```groovy
class Breakfast {

    String meat
    String eggs
    String side
    Integer number // Just another random propperty 

    static constraints = {
    }

    // Generic version, We asume we need allCaps for all String properties  
    def asMap(boolean allCaps=false) {
        def breakfast = [:]
        this.properties.each { key, value ->
            if (value && value.class == String && allCaps == true) {
                breakfast[key] = value.toUpperCase() 
            } else {
                breakfast[key] = value
            } 
        }
        return breakfast
    }

    // An alternate/sillier version 
    def asMapSimpler(boolean allCaps=false) {
        return [
            meat:meat.toUpperCase(),
            eggs:eggs.toUpperCase(),
            side:side.toUpperCase(),
            number: number
        ]
    }

}
```

**Next**, we can use the `asMap` method in `FooController`:

```groovy
class FooController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    
    def index() {

        // default: false 
        def allCaps = params.boolean("allCaps") ?: false

        Map<String, Map> mealsByPerson = [
            Tom: new Breakfast(meat: "bacon", eggs: "scrambled", side: "hashbrowns").asMap(allCaps),
            Jack: new Breakfast(meat: "sausage", eggs: "over easy", side: "pancakes").asMap(allCaps)
        ]

        render template: "foo", model: [
            cost: 12.34f,
            date: new Date(),
            mealsByPerson: mealsByPerson,
            allCaps: allCaps
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Do `def allCaps = params.boolean("allCaps") ?: false` and `boolean allCaps = params.boolean("allCaps")` have the exact same behavior?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown , yes, it appears so. I just tested this code with both versions of that statement.  Both generated `java.lang.Boolean` variables with the exact same value in each possible case: true, false, not specified, or specifying an invalid value.

Comment: Is this the best way?   Is there no way to get the JSON view to use the `_breaskfast.gson` template when rendering a `Map<String, Breakfast>`.  My real-world domain object is much more complex, and I already have a template that renders it well.  If I use an `asMap` method, I'll have to duplicate some of the rendering logic already included in the gson template. @JeffScottBrown

Comment: "Is this the best way? " - It isn't objectively "best", no.  One argument against this approach is that it puts presentation logic in the model class.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, yes. However `boolean allCaps = ...` is more type-safe, of course

Comment: "However boolean allCaps = ... is more type-safe..." - More type safe than what?

Comment: Yes, for sure there are better ways to do this. Unfortunately, I haven't much experience with JSON views (gson files). I agree that presentation logic in the model class is not orthodox. Probably a seasoned Grails programmer would suggest using a Service. I just plain didn't intend to suggest anything more than a practical/feasible solution. Having said that, yesterday I managed to move my solution to the gson file, but I just ended up programming with groovy there, which IMO is not and elegant solution either, so decided to leave it as is.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown "More type safe than what?" - I just meant, generally speaking, that  `AnyType foo=...` in Groovy is (kind of) a type-safer assignation, compared to `def  foo=...`. Of course, Boolean is an exception in Groovy, due to [The Groovy Truth](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth)

Comment: "Having said that, yesterday I managed to move my solution to the gson file, but I just ended up programming with groovy there, which IMO is not and elegant solution either, so decided to leave it as is." - Groovy is the only language we support in gson files and moving this logic to the view layer is the correct thing to do.  If you are putting a lot of imperative logic in the GSON files then helpers will be in order, but moving to the view layer is the right move.  Well done!

Answer (score 0):

## Revisiting the problem

I revisited the problem and my previous answer, and decided to post this one instead of editing the former, addressing here a couple of comments/suggestions received to improve my proposed solution.

I moved presentation logic away from the domain class. To achieve that, I've explored three different approaches:

1. Using a Grails Service
2. Coding in the JSON View side
3. Using only templates

Just for the sake of clarity, I added the following mappings in `URLMappings.groovy`:

```groovy
   "/approach1"(controller: 'foo', action:'approach1')
   "/approach2"(controller: 'foo', action:'approach2')
   "/approach3"(controller: 'foo', action:'approach3')
```

### Approach 1: Using a Grails Service

Please note that in `FooController` the service bean `fooService` is included as a parameter in the `respond` call to the JSON View.

***FooService.groovy***

```groovy
package rendermapexample

import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional

@Transactional
class FooService {

    def toAllCaps(mealsByPerson) {        
        mealsByPerson.each { person, breakfast ->
            def breakfastMap = [:]
            breakfast.properties.each { key, value ->
                if (value && value.class == String) {
                    breakfastMap[key] = value.toUpperCase() 
                } else {
                    breakfastMap[key] = value
                } 
            }
            mealsByPerson[person] = breakfastMap 
        }
        return mealsByPerson
    }

}
```

***FooController.groovy***

```groovy
package rendermapexample

class FooController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    def fooService

    def approach1() {

        Map<String, Breakfast>  mealsByPerson = [
            Tom: new Breakfast(meat: "bacon", eggs: "scrambled", side: "hashbrowns"),
            Jack: new Breakfast(meat: "sausage", eggs: "over easy", side: "pancakes")
        ]

        respond cost: 12.34f,
                date: new Date(),
                mealsByPerson: mealsByPerson,
                allCaps: params.boolean("allCaps"),
                fooService: fooService
        
    }
}
```

***approach1.gson***

```groovy
import rendermapexample.Breakfast
import rendermapexample.FooService

model {
    Float cost
    Date date
    Map<String, Breakfast> mealsByPerson
    Boolean allCaps
    FooService fooService
}

json {
    date date
    cost cost   
    mealsByPerson g.render(allCaps ? fooService.toAllCaps(mealsByPerson) : mealsByPerson)
}
```

Of course, instead of passing the `fooService` bean as a parameter, we could place `toAllCaps` code into a POJO static utility class, and then import it in `approach2.gson`.

### Approach 2: Coding in the JSON View side

In case more control is needed on the JSON View side, we could move `toAllCaps` function from `FooService.groovy` to `approach1.gson`, and just discard `FooService.groovy`.

***FooController.groovy***

```groovy
package rendermapexample

class FooController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    def approach2() {

        Map<String, Breakfast>  mealsByPerson = [
            Tom: new Breakfast(meat: "bacon", eggs: "scrambled", side: "hashbrowns"),
            Jack: new Breakfast(meat: "sausage", eggs: "over easy", side: "pancakes")
        ]

        respond cost: 12.34f,
                date: new Date(),
                mealsByPerson: mealsByPerson,
                allCaps: params.boolean("allCaps")
        
    }
}
```

***approach2.gson***

```groovy
import rendermapexample.Breakfast

model {
    Float cost
    Date date
    Map<String, Breakfast> mealsByPerson
    Boolean allCaps
}

json {
    date date
    cost cost   
    mealsByPerson g.render(allCaps ? toAllCaps(mealsByPerson) : mealsByPerson)
}


def toAllCaps(mealsByPerson) {        
    mealsByPerson.each { person, breakfast ->
        def breakfastMap = [:]
        breakfast.properties.each { key, value ->
            if (value && value.class == String) {
                breakfastMap[key] = value.toUpperCase() 
            } else {
                breakfastMap[key] = value
            } 
        }
        mealsByPerson[person] = breakfastMap 
    }
    return mealsByPerson
}
```

### Approach 3: Using only templates

Here I intended to do less traditional groovy coding, and rely more on JSON View templates, as [outlined](https://views.grails.org/latest/#_templates) in the official documentation.

Please note the following caveats:

1. I'm using an `ArrayList` variant of `mealsByPerson` because some features of JSON View templates require an object that implements the `Iterator` interface.  **Important:** This results in a JSON Array of separate, individual objects rather than a single JSON object containing all the map entries as described in the original question.
2. I had to disable static compilation for JSON Views. This is because some of the JSON object names within `mealsByPerson` are dynamic (i.e. they are not just labels but actual data). Namely "Tom" and "Jack" object names from the original post.

***application.yml***

```yml
grails:
    views:
        json:
            compileStatic: false
```

***FooController.groovy***

```groovy
package rendermapexample

class FooController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    def approach3() {
        
        ArrayList mealsByPerson = [
            Tom: new Breakfast(meat: "bacon", eggs: "scrambled", side: "hashbrowns"),
            Jack: new Breakfast(meat: "sausage", eggs: "over easy", side: "pancakes")
        ].collect()

        respond cost: 12.34f,
                date: new Date(),
                mealsByPerson: mealsByPerson,
                allCaps: params.boolean("allCaps")
    }
}
```

***approach3.gson***

```groovy
import rendermapexample.Breakfast

model {
    Float cost
    Date date
    ArrayList mealsByPerson
    Boolean allCaps
}

json {
    date date
    cost cost   
    mealsByPerson tmpl.mealsByPerson(mealsByPerson, [allCaps: allCaps]) 
}
```

***_mealsByPerson.gson***

```groovy
import rendermapexample.Breakfast

model {
    Map.Entry mealsByPerson
    Boolean allCaps
}

String person = mealsByPerson.key
Breakfast breakfast = mealsByPerson.value

json {
    "${person}" tmpl.breakfast(breakfast:breakfast, allCaps:allCaps) 
}
```

***_breakfast.gson***

```groovy
import rendermapexample.Breakfast

model {
    Breakfast breakfast
    Boolean allCaps
}


json {
    if (allCaps) {
        meat breakfast.meat.toUpperCase()
        eggs breakfast.eggs.toUpperCase()
        side breakfast.side.toUpperCase()
    } else {
        meat breakfast.meat
        eggs breakfast.eggs
        side breakfast.side
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding `g.render(allCaps ? fooService.toAllCaps(mealsByPerson) : mealsByPerson)` is there a reason that you prefer the boolean logic to be in the view rather than the service, as opposed to calling something like `fooService.renderMealsByPerson(mealsByPerson, allCaps)`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown No, no preference at all. I think I misunderstood or misremembered a comment from the original post owner, in the sense that he was looking for having more control on the view side. Probably I just misread it.

Comment: I really like the 3rd approach of moving the logic into separate modular JSON views.  That's precisely what I was hoping for.  It will allow me to reuse other JSON views (i.e. `_breakfast.gson`) that I've already built.  

I'm going to try this out and, assuming it works, will accept this answer. Thanks, @rchfox and @JeffScottBrown for all the help!

Comment: As it turns out the 3rd approach didn't work because it converted the map entries into a JSON array of individual JSON objects with a single property each.  What I want is a single JSON object with a property for each map entry.  Here's a gist with the actual and expected JSON objects: https://gist.github.com/tonyerskine/2345fee79a2a5618c1d588cdb7edfe20